# iPhone Mapkit adding custom image and pins to annotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to change the pin colour from the default red to a custom image but whatever I am trying just isn't working.

I have downloaded the sample code from this website:

http://icodeblog.com/2009/12/21/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0/

The code works on it's own but when I import the annotation classes into my code, they do not work and I have no idea why. I have also tried a number of different methods from other sites but I can't even get the pin colour to change.

My project has 4 tabs and the MapView is on one of the tabs. When I select it, it parses a JSON string and adds the separate annotations onto the map. i have the title and subtitle showing up when I click on the pin, but cannot change the colour or image.

Here is how I add my annotations - MapAnnotation follows MKAnnotation:

```
MapAnnotation *ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord];
    ann.title = [locationDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    ann.subtitle = [locationDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [ann release]
```

Here is how I try and attempt to change the colour - I have MapView.delegate=self in the view controller:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:[annotation title]];

if (pin == nil) {
    pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]] autorelease];
}else {
    pin.annotation = annotation;
}

pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
pin.animatesDrop = YES;
pin.canShowCallout = TRUE;
return pin;
```

}

I get the annotations to appear with title and subtitle, just not green markers. They're always red wether I use colours or images. If anyone could help me out, that would be great!

Thanks

EDIT:

The mapView delegate is assigned in the viewDidLoad method. I also add an Overlay to a certain part of the map. This is working fine, I have also taken it out and tried it without that incase it was causing a problem but it still didn't fix it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MKCoordinateRegion cordRgn;

LusuAppAppDelegate *delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if (delegate.CurrentLocation == 0) {
    cordRgn.center.latitude = (CENTRE_OF_POSITION_2_LAT);
    cordRgn.center.longitude = (CENTRE_OF_POSITION_2_LON);
    delegate.CurrentLocation = 1;
}else if (delegate.CurrentLocation == 1) {
    cordRgn.center.latitude = (CENTRE_OF_POSITION_1_LAT);
    cordRgn.center.longitude = (CENTRE_OF_POSITION_1_LON);  
    delegate.CurrentLocation = 0;
}

cordRgn.span.latitudeDelta = 0.009f;
cordRgn.span.longitudeDelta = 0.009f;


self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

//add overlay
MKRasterOverlay *overlay = [[MKRasterOverlay alloc] init];
[overlay setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.005508, -2.780507)];

MKMapRect mkrect;
MKMapPoint mkpointa, mkpointb;
mkrect.origin = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.016964, -2.794862));
mkpointa = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.016964, 2.000000));
mkpointb = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.001447, 2.013770));
mkrect.size.width = mkpointb.x - mkpointa.x;
mkrect.size.height = mkpointb.y - mkpointa.y;
overlay.boundingMapRect = mkrect;

mapView.delegate = self;

[mapView addOverlay:overlay];
[mapView setRegion:cordRgn animated:NO];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

[self doAnnotations];
```

}

The doAnnotations function is the code shown above but in a loop. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.  I suspect you have an error in your delegate assignment and `mapView:viewForAnimation` is not actually being called.  An MKMapView without a delegate providing that function will work fine, with red pins for all annotations.  Try adding some `NSLog` statements or setting a breakpoint in the debugger to make sure you're actually executing this code.

You probably already know this, but using your own images will require you to create pins that are `MKAnnotationView`s rather than `MKAnnotationPinView`s.

Comment: Yeah your correct, it's not actually being called. What could I be doing wrong? I have mapView.delegate = self in the code, only difference I could see in mine from the example is that in dealloc I have mapView.delegate = nil. Without that line though, I get an error. Shouldn't be causing the problem though should it?

Comment: The dealloc line shouldn't be related.  Show us the function where you assign the delegate property and maybe we can spot something there.

Comment: I've amended my original post to include how I set the delegate. This is done in the viewDidLoad method. Thanks again.

Comment: That the overlay appears but viewForAnnotation isn't called is vexing. Double check, though, to be absolutely sure that you've got a non-nil value in mapView (that it's properly connected in IB).  You also might try setting the delegate property in IB rather than in code, to ensure that there's no ordering problem where the map adds the annotations and calls viewForAnnotation before it has a valid delegate.