# iOS MapKit custom pins

Tags: ios, mapkit

How do I show images instead of pins in the map. So far I can only add pins on tap. A sample code of the .m would extremely help since i'm still new to iOS programming.

Comment: A little search goes a long way :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579397/iphone-mapkit-adding-custom-image-and-pins-to-annotations and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124028/change-pin-design

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MKMapView delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if(annotationView)
        return annotationView;
    else
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                         reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(writeSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
 }
```

EDIT:

I could explain to you all about the `MKAnnotationView`, but I think you will find the documentation provided by Apple to be a far better explanation than from any other source. Check the overview section in the link.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview

Comment: it works. thanks. could you please include a brief explanation about the parameters passed and what the annotation identifier is? is that similar to .net's tag property?

Comment: Instead of using "someImage.png", in my requirement, i've to draw on UIView and using [annotationView addSubView:myView]. Its working fine. But not calling "didSelectAnnotationView" on tap of it. Anything wrong?

Comment: May be you need to disable the user interaction of that view.

Comment: Why are you setting title to the button of UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure type ? Does it make any sense ?

Comment: This was the sample code that I took from one of my projects.

Comment: If you want to set user's location with custom point, then comment these lines from above. `if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;`

Answer (score 6):

Go to organizer of Xcode and then go to documentation and search weatherMap it shows example for map with including images at annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MKMapView delegate
-(void)addAllPinsOnMapView
{



MKCoordinateRegion region = mapViewOffer.region;
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9752297537231, 80.2313079833984);
region.span.longitudeDelta= 0.1f;
region.span.latitudeDelta= 0.1f;
[mapViewOffer setRegion:region animated:YES];






mapViewOffer.delegate=self;
arrMapPin=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *name=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
               @"Title1",
               @"Title2",
               @"Title3", nil];

NSMutableArray *arrCoordinateStr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:name.count];
[arrCoordinateStr addObject:@"12.970760345459,80.2190093994141"];
[arrCoordinateStr addObject:@"12.9752297537231,80.2313079833984"];
[arrCoordinateStr addObject:@"12.9788103103638,80.2412414550781"];

for(int i = 0; i < name.count; i++)
{
    NSArray *components = [[arrCoordinateStr objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    double latitude = [components[0] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [components[1] doubleValue];

    MKPointAnnotation *mapPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    mapPin.title = [name objectAtIndex:i];
    mapPin.coordinate = coordinate;
    [mapViewOffer addAnnotation:mapPin];
}
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:
(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.title);
NSLog(@"%f",view.annotation.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"%f",view.annotation.coordinate.longitude);

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(calloutTapped:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

}
-(void)calloutTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
NSLog(@"Callout was tapped");

MKAnnotationView *view = (MKAnnotationView*)sender.view;
id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [view annotation];
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
{
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"annotationDetailSegue" sender:annotation];
    OfferDetailsViewController *objOfferDetailsViewController = [[OfferDetailsViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objOfferDetailsViewController animated:YES];
}
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView 
viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
static NSString *defaultPinID = @"annotationViewID";
pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapViewOffer dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
if ( pinView == nil ){
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
}

pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];


UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

return pinView;
}
```

Comment: add a few description before posting a long code snippet.