# How to set Image on DROP PIN in iOS MAP?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

Normally, By default iOS image for drop pin looks like as below

[image: DROP PIN]

I want to display custom image instead of this pin, which method or way facilitates it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS MapKit custom pins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145797/ios-mapkit-custom-pins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView

Answer (score 1):

For a better idea, this tut could help you:

http://www.shawngrimes.me/2011/04/custom-map-pins-for-mapkit/